# Display table layout broken in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Tried this in every major browser (Chrome/Safari/IE/Edge) and Firefox. Works in everything but Firefox where the text gets nudged down.

```css
.auto-height {
display: table;
height: 100%;
}
.full-height-section {
display: table-cell;
height: 100%;
width: 49%;
background-image: url("https://preview.ibb.co/iNcv0f/ladysquats.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
.half-content {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 60px 30px;
}
.half-content h2, .half-content p, .half-content ul {
text-align: center;
}
.half-content .img-size-payment-type {
width: 65%;
}
button.colour-dark-pnk, button.colour-light {
font-size: 1em;
margin-top: 25px;
padding: 10px 60px;
border: 0 solid #f4a2a4;
border-radius: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="how-works-section-six-container auto-height mobile-screen-hide">
<div class="full-height-section">
</div>
<div class="section-six half-content">
<h2>IPSUM LOREM</h2>
<p>  <img class="img-size-payment-type" src="https://preview.ibb.co/f0Ea0f/metodos-pago.png"><br>
  <a href="/shop"><button class="colour-dark-pnk">Order now</button></a></p>
<h2 class="font-colour-dark-pnk">Test Title</h2>
<p>Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem:</p>
<ul class="box-pnk">
<li>Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem.</li>
<li>Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem.</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

What it looks like in FF:
[image]

What's even weirder is that the problem disappears as soon 'Inspect Element' is used, meaning it's very hard to see what's going on. Looks like an actual Browser bug?

Comment: sorry, I got distracted by something. what was your question? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/c3bfzLhj/

Change all `height:100%` to `min-height:100%`
This is a Firefox bug. I had faced this problem two weeks ago while working on my web app.